# Ninja Forms - Select Options field not updating when editing a submission

Tags: php, forms, ninja-forms

I have a field "Status" that the user needs to change to "approved" when editing any submissions.

**Replication steps**

- Create a form with a select or radio list
- Submit the form
- View the submission
- Edit the values selected for the lists and save
- The data will default to the original choices that were made during
  the initial submission